# Neither initb -D nor a changed data_direectoy is recognized by postgresql service

Tags: postgresql, centos, centos7

I want to change the data_directory of my postgresql database cluster. I found 2 ways to do this, non of them work for me.

From documentation what I do is:

```
yum install postgresql-server
create new linux user "postgres"
sudo mkdir /home2
sudo mkdir /home2/data
sudo chown postgres:postgres /home2
sudo chown postgres:postgres /home2/data
```

Now the trouble begins in both cases:

**Variant 1**:

```
✘ root@localhost /var/lib/pgsql/data # postgresql-setup initdb
Initializing database ... OK

✘ root@localhost /var/lib/pgsql/data # l
total 44K
drwx------. 15 postgres postgres 4.0K May 17 08:02 .
drwx------.  4 postgres postgres   72 May 16 15:17 ..
drwx------.  5 postgres postgres   41 May 17 08:02 base
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres 4.0K May 17 08:02 global
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres   18 May 17 08:02 pg_clog
-rw-------.  1 postgres postgres 4.2K May 17 08:02 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------.  1 postgres postgres 1.6K May 17 08:02 pg_ident.conf
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres    6 May 17 08:02 pg_log
drwx------.  4 postgres postgres   36 May 17 08:02 pg_multixact
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres   18 May 17 08:02 pg_notify
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres    6 May 17 08:02 pg_serial
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres    6 May 17 08:02 pg_snapshots
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres    6 May 17 08:02 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres   18 May 17 08:02 pg_subtrans
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres    6 May 17 08:02 pg_tblspc
drwx------.  2 postgres postgres    6 May 17 08:02 pg_twophase
-rw-------.  1 postgres postgres    4 May 17 08:02 PG_VERSION
drwx------.  3 postgres postgres   60 May 17 08:02 pg_xlog
-rw-------.  1 postgres postgres  20K May 17 08:02 postgresql.conf
root@localhost /var/lib/pgsql/data #
```

Starting a terminal as postgres-user:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.2.24)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SHOW data_directory;
   data_directory    
---------------------
 /var/lib/pgsql/data
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

I did `systemctl stop psotgresql`, edited the `postgresql.conf` and changed `data_directory = '/home2/data'`. When I do `systemctl start psotgresql` I get

```
FATAL:  "/home2/data" is not a valid data directory
DETAIL:  File "/home2/data/PG_VERSION" is missing.
```

so I did

```
-bash-4.2$ initdb -D /home2/data
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

fixing permissions on existing directory /home2/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 32MB
creating configuration files ... ok
creating template1 database in /home2/data/base/1 ... ok
initializing pg_authid ... ok
initializing dependencies ... ok
creating system views ... ok
loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
creating collations ... ok
creating conversions ... ok
creating dictionaries ... ok
setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
creating information schema ... ok
loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
vacuuming database template1 ... ok
copying template1 to template0 ... ok
copying template1 to postgres ... ok

WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    postgres -D /home2/data
or
    pg_ctl -D /home2/data -l logfile start

-bash-4.2$
```

as postgres user. When I try to start the postgresql server again using `systemctl start postgresql` the terminal won't finish

```
root@localhost /var/lib/pgsql/data # systemctl start postgresql
```

but the server is running, I can login as postgres user

```
-bash-4.2$ psql
psql (9.2.24)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# SHOW data_directory;
 data_directory 
----------------
 /home2/data
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

What is going wrong here? Why doesn't the service "prompt" finish? After quite some time the service is getting a timeout and coming back. The database doesn't run anymore then.

> Job for postgresql.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
>   ✘ root@localhost /var/lib/pgsql/data #

---

**Variant 2**:

New fresh local VM did the steps from the top until the trouble begins:

```
-bash-4.2$ initdb -D /home2/data
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf-8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

fixing permissions on existing directory /home2/data ... ok
creating subdirectories ... ok
selecting default max_connections ... 100
selecting default shared_buffers ... 32MB
creating configuration files ... ok
creating template1 database in /home2/data/base/1 ... ok
initializing pg_authid ... ok
initializing dependencies ... ok
creating system views ... ok
loading system objects' descriptions ... ok
creating collations ... ok
creating conversions ... ok
creating dictionaries ... ok
setting privileges on built-in objects ... ok
creating information schema ... ok
loading PL/pgSQL server-side language ... ok
vacuuming database template1 ... ok
copying template1 to template0 ... ok
copying template1 to postgres ... ok

WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.

Success. You can now start the database server using:

    postgres -D /home2/data
or
    pg_ctl -D /home2/data -l logfile start

-bash-4.2$ ls -l /home2/data/
total 40
drwx------. 5 postgres postgres    41 May 17 08:20 base
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres  4096 May 17 08:20 global
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    18 May 17 08:20 pg_clog
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  4476 May 17 08:20 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres  1636 May 17 08:20 pg_ident.conf
drwx------. 4 postgres postgres    36 May 17 08:20 pg_multixact
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    18 May 17 08:20 pg_notify
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 May 17 08:20 pg_serial
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 May 17 08:20 pg_snapshots
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 May 17 08:20 pg_stat_tmp
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres    18 May 17 08:20 pg_subtrans
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 May 17 08:20 pg_tblspc
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres     6 May 17 08:20 pg_twophase
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres     4 May 17 08:20 PG_VERSION
drwx------. 3 postgres postgres    60 May 17 08:20 pg_xlog
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 19865 May 17 08:20 postgresql.conf
-bash-4.2$
```

When trying to start the postgresql service

```
✘ root@localhost /var/lib/pgsql/data # systemctl restart postgresql
Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
✘ root@localhost /var/lib/pgsql/data # journalctl -xe
...
May 17 08:20:58 localhost.localdomain postgresql-check-db-dir[15283]: "/var/lib/pgsql/data" is missing or empty.
May 17 08:20:58 localhost.localdomain postgresql-check-db-dir[15283]: Use "postgresql-setup initdb" to initialize the database cluster.
May 17 08:20:58 localhost.localdomain postgresql-check-db-dir[15283]: See /usr/share/doc/postgresql-9.2.24/README.rpm-dist for more information.
May 17 08:20:58 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 17 08:20:58 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL database server.
...
```

so the postgresql-service doesn't see I already did initdb. When I do `postgresql-setup initdb` it simply creates the data directory unter the default location. Running the postgresql as postgres user `postgres -D /home2/data` does work, but I had to create some kind of service out of this command so I won't have to keep my terminal opened.

Environment: CentOS 7
I'm doing a first test-installation in a local vagrant box. While doing this I write code in ansible. So usually I'm not using the root user ;)

Comment: I would like to just chip in and say that version 9.2.24 has not been supported for year and a half now. Why not give a try a newer version?

Comment: Tbh, I haven't even recognized any version number. Gonna have to take a look on this. Could be due to my ansible playbook where I said "install present" and not "install latest". Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Look at the PostgreSQL log file(s). The obvious cause for the problem is that the second server is also configured to listen on port 5432, which is already in use.

Comment: There is no other server running. The port is not in use. I may got a solution for my problems, I'm doing a couple tests currently to verfiy everything seems to be fine imho then I'm going to post/edit to show my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Probably the solution for my issues

After doing some research I found a [guide](https://pgstef.github.io/2018/02/28/custom_pgdata_with_systemd.html) which brought me a little further to my solution. After taking a look into my `cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service` There was a part saying

```
# It's not recommended to modify this file in-place, because it will be
# overwritten during package upgrades.  If you want to customize, the
# best way is to create a file "/etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service",
# containing
#   .include /lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
#   ...make your changes here...
```

so I did this:

```
# vi /etc/systemd/system/postgresql.service
.include /lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service
[Service]
Environment=PGDATA=/home2/data
```

and finally I can just simply do `postgresql-setup initdb` and my database-cluster is getting installed into the correct directory and I can use my system-services just like it's meant to be.

I will mark this as solution as soon as I can confirm the database is running fine without having any trouble.